# Graphing a line in slope intercept

Tags: calculus

Can you help with this problem?

Which of the following is equation of a line whose slope is 7 and y-intercept is 3?

```
7 y = x + 3
y = 3x + 7
y = 7x + 3
3y = x + 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation of a line is $y=mx+c$, where $m$ is slope and $c$ is the $y$-intercept.

Compare and get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will accept it :) Can you help with this question? \[ Let\,\,f(x)\,\, = \,\frac{{x + 1}} {{x - 1}}\,\,\,\,\,then\,\,f(1)\,\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \] the the answer will be 0, 1, 2 or Not defined ?

Comment: @user148742 Not defined as the function after putting x=1 will yield $\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: Are you sure with this answer not defined?

Comment: @user148742 yes i am.